# Incremental Deployment locking anonymous sites

Tags: 2007, content-deployment

i have a staging environment and a production environment . The production environment setting is Allow Anonymous access to the Entire Website. Two times we have observed that once after a content deployment the The Anonymous setting gets reverted back to nothing, so we need to login to the Prod site and enable anonymous again. which i dont know why its happening?

We know the reason why its happening when we create a new site in staging environment and when we do an incremental deployment this happens.

Can somebody let me know how to solve this

Thanks in Advance

Thomson

Comment: Are you using custom site definitions for the sites?

Comment: can you explain how the content deployment is done? can you try making your staging environment to allow anonymous and do a content deployment and check whats happening?

Answer (score 1):

We figured out this problem. This happens when you create a new site in Stage . In our onet.xml when we provision a site a default page is created (default.aspx). and we have made it as draft. So if we do not publish this page manually and do the ContentDeployment . It will lock the sites. Then we need to explicitly enable anonymous access

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your problem specifically.  Not sure how you are performing your deployment.  I will say that if the SPWebApplicaiton or the SPWebService is unprovisioned and reprovisioned all custom IIS settings are lost.